# Get id name of a clicked shape in a google maps kml

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

https://mapsengine.google.com/map/viewer?mid=zpGDoaxhx2Js.kTED__uPzdIE

I have a map with this KML. It loads perfectly, i just want to get the id of the clicked shape.

I know i can listen with this, but I don't know how to continue.

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(event) { }
```

This is my code right now

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {{ asset("bundles/Estadisticas/css/mapa.css") }}" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">


var map;
var src = 'http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=42027229668711716761&t=4202722966871171676165346';

/**
 * Initializes the map and calls the function that creates polylines.
 */
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.6023448, -58.3810855),
  zoom: 2,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
});
loadKmlLayer(src, map);
}

/**
 * Adds a KMLLayer based on the URL passed. Clicking on a marker
 * results in the balloon content being loaded into the right-hand div.
 * @param {string} src A URL for a KML file.
 */
 function loadKmlLayer(src, map) {
  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
  suppressInfoWindows: true,
  preserveViewport: false,
  map: map
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
    var text = kmlEvent.featureData.name;
    showInContentWindow(text);
 });

 function showInContentWindow(text) {
    var sidediv = document.getElementById('content-window');
    sidediv.innerHTML = text;
 }
}

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

 </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a javascript error with the code as posted:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

You don't have a div with id="content-window"

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jNLa/)

updated HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;"></div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <div id="content-window"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data from the KML lives within the event object:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(event) {
    console.log(event.featureData.id);
});
```

The featureData object contains most of the information within your Placemark tag in the KML file. So on each click, you can compare or manipulate that information as needed.